# Update 2 for Visual Studio 2015 not starting

Tags: visual-studio-2015, failed-installation

I currently have VS 2015 Community Edition Update 1 installed on a Windows 10 Lenovo Thinkpad.

Today I got the notification that Update 2 for VS 2015 is available. So I downloaded and executed the installer. It then seemed to download additional content. Afterwards the install dialog opened but closed again within a fraction of a second. There is no error shown whatsoever, it simply closes. Even within the event log I couldn't find anything.

There are also a couple of other updates available, so I thought it maybe helps if I install them first. Some installed without problem (e.g. git extension), but others showed the exact same behavior as Update 2 (e.g. Application Insights, TypeScript).

Also here I don't receive any error, the update simply closes in a fraction of a second.

Of course I already googled, but couldn't find any solution. Does anyone else have the same problem? How can I solve this?

Thanks for your help,
Dante

Comment: why don't you ask in the microsoft forums?

Comment: because usually stackoverflow provides far better answers than any other forum

Comment: yes and it's for programming questions only and this one is very borderline

Comment: sorry for that, actually I didn't realize this forum is for programming questions only, as I've seen many others asking similar questions

Comment: yes and those should be closed as well - please read the FAQs

Comment: Well, according to ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "[...] if your question generally covers [...] software tools commonly used by programmers [...] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"
And Visual Studio is a software tool (IDE) commonly used by programmers. So I really don't think my question is off topic.